# How to change current link color on my current page?

Tags: jquery, css, permalinks

I can't change my current link color. If I click one of my link, then it will go to the specified URL, but the color of the current link that opened is not change. Still showing the same color as the other links that were not active.

My website is http://lineswork.com/beta/architecture

You can try to click on the right links, V2 and dragofly. The page change but the color is not change. Please kindly help me.

Thanks.

Comment: please share some relevant code for which you are facing problem and explain it exactly what is happening, this way people may help you better.

Comment: What I need is, if I visit lineswork.com/beta/architecture/v2 , then the only color that changed is only for V2 link on the right. The rest is still the default color. And it happen the same to the other links if I clicked and go to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class, for example `selected`, to the link and try this CSS style.

```
.selected{
   color: #a0160d;
}
```

Put `<?php $current_id = $post->ID; ?>` outside the loop.

Then, change your code

```
<div id="architecture-wrap-right">
  <?php //get post type ==> architecture query_posts(array( 'post_type'=>'architecture', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged'=>$paged )); ?>
  <div class="architecture-item-details"> <div class="architecture-title">
    <a <?php if ( $current_id == $post->ID ) echo 'class="selected"'; ?> href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
</div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: I just did that, but not working. It change all the links color on the right. What I need is, if I visit http://lineswork.com/beta/architecture/v2 , then the only color that changed is only for V2 link on the right. The rest is still the default color.

Comment: Do not add class `selected` to all the link. Add class to the link that you want to change the color.

Comment: I use href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> to get all of the link on my portfolio page. So I just put the class <a class="selected" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>>

Comment: Is there anyway to put class on current link if I use href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> ?

Comment: Are you using wordpress?

Comment: `<div id="architecture-wrap-right">
<?php 
//get post type ==> architecture query_posts(array( 'post_type'=>'architecture', 
'posts_per_page' => 10, 
'paged'=>$paged )); ?> 

<div class="architecture-item-details"> 
<div class="architecture-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></div> 
</div> 
</div>`

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check it.

Answer (score -1):

```
a:visited { 
    background-color: Red; 
}
```